# Execute PHP inside SCRIPT TAG

Tags: javascript, php

I have a listbox that displays a couple of internships under following format

id - name :
    1   - Computer Science

So far, I have create the function addRow in order to update my fields from form.
If I do

> alert($montext)

I can display "1 - Computer Science", but I am looking only for the value "1".
I tried :

```
alert(<?php substr($montext,0,2)?>);
```

But seems that php inside "script" isn't being executed.

Because following code changes the value in the field:

```
document.getElementById('ti').value=$montext;
```

Because I'd like also to execute php code inside the script TAG.

I'm running under Apache.

If you could help me out. Thanks

Find hereby the used code.

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function addRow(title,text,description,id) {
        $montext=$( "#idStage option:selected" ).text();
        alert($montext);
        document.getElementById('ti').value=$montext;
            /*document.getElementById('te').value=text;
            document.getElementById('de').value=description;
            document.getElementById('id').value=id;*/
    }

        function setText(title,text,description,id){

            document.getElementById('title').value=title;
            document.getElementById('text').value=text;
            document.getElementById('description').value=description;
            document.getElementById('id').value=id;
        }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
        include('../admin/connect_db.php');
    ?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
          <td>
          <label class="notBold">Choose the internship you want to update: </label>
                <select name="idStage" id="idStage" onChange="addRow()">
                <?php
                    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
                    if($stmt->prepare('SELECT id, title,text,description FROM offre ORDER by published_date ASC')) {
                        $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$text,$description);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        while($stmt->fetch()){
                ?>
                            <option id="nostage" value="<?php echo$id;?>" onclick="setText('<?php echo $title ?>',' <?php echo $text ?> ',' <?php echo $description ?>',' <?php echo $id?>');"><?php echo $id." - ".$title;?></option>
                <?php       
                        }
                        $stmt->close();
                    }
                ?>
                </select>&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td width="20">
            <img src="./Image/exit.png" title="Close" id="closeDelete" class="closeOpt" onclick="closeOpt()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

        <form method="post" action="modifystage.php">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type = "hidden" id ="id" name="id"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                <label>Title&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <textarea id = "ti" name="ti" rows = "3" cols = "75">
                <?php 
                $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
                    if($stmt->prepare('SELECT id, title,text,description FROM offre ORDER by published_date ASC')) {
                        $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$text,$description);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        }
                    echo $title;
                ?>
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td class="label">
                <label>Desc</label>

                <textarea id = "de" name="de" rows = "3" cols = "75">
                <?php 
                $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
                    if($stmt->prepare('SELECT id, title,text,description FROM offre ORDER by published_date ASC')) {
                        $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$text,$description);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        }
                    echo $description;
                ?>
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                <label>Text&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <textarea id = "te" name="te" rows = "3" cols = "75">
                <?php 
                $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
                    if($stmt->prepare('SELECT id, title,text,description FROM offre ORDER by published_date ASC')) {
                        $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$text,$description);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        }
                    echo $text;
                ?>
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"colspan="2" class="label">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you woul ned to ue `echo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use PHP here.  Use the javascript `substring` function - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

For example

```
alert(montext.substring(0, 2));
```

Comment: Please note that javascript runs on the client side, while PHP runs on the server side. When you use PHP to call a variable inside of javascript code, it gets set the moment the user asks for the webpage, NOT when the user selects an item from the drop-down select box.

Comment: It works. I tried the code from ghostzali, but unforthunately, when I select my menu, it doesn't open my window. But this method works fine. bow

Answer (score 2):

Write your `<script>` on bellow your PHP and try this :

```
<script>
    function addRow(title,text,description,id) {
        var montext = $( "#idStage" ).text();
        alert(montext);
        document.getElementById('ti').value(montext);
            /*document.getElementById('te').value=text;
            document.getElementById('de').value=description;
            document.getElementById('id').value=id;*/
    }

    function setText(title,text,description,id){

        document.getElementById('title').value=title;
        document.getElementById('text').value=text;
        document.getElementById('description').value=description;
        document.getElementById('id').value=id;
    }
</script>
```

If you want to call variable from PHP, don't forget to use `echo` like this :

```
alert("<?php echo substr($montext,0,2); ?>");
```